# How to write to Z drive by using fopen()?

Tags: php

I have mentioned the below code.

```
  $commandFile = "contains the some big string"; 
  if($fp = fopen("file:///Z:/testName.txt","w+"))
  {
    fwrite($fp,$commandFile);
    fclose($fp);
  }
```

Z drive has the user credentials i.e (username:network,Pass:network). Z drive is mapped to my computer. How to write this file to Z drive?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If this `Z` is regular drive **on machine running the script**, then plain:

```
fopen('Z:/testName.txt',"w+")
```

should be sufficient.